# How can I reliably pick up boring stones that sit atop beams I cut down?

Tags: tiny-and-big

In Tiny & Big: Grandpa's Leftovers, getting across a ravine is often accomplished by cutting down an overhead beam. At times, these beams will have boring stones sitting on them that you can pick up. Pictured below is such a case:
[image: Beam with stones]

The problem is, that more often than not cutting the beam would have it fall down at an angle, which would cause at least one of the stones to fall off of it and into the ravine, making it unattainable. I've tried cutting down such beams in many different ways, but have been unable to find a way that would consistently prevent the beam from falling down at an angle (necessitating many many reloads until I finally lucked out).

Is there a technique that I have simply not been able to figure out?

Comment: A good trick is to try to face the block as directly as you can when you cut it.  The straighter you are, the straighter you cut, and that will help it fall less obstructed.  There is a particular trick to this room I think, but I can't remember what it is right now.  I'll try to figure it out again when I have a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you want to make a cut beam fall as directly as possible, you want to make a perfectly vertical cut across the beam.  This means you should face a flat side of the beam as directly as possible, which *also* means you should try to cut from the same height as the beam.  Any height difference will severely narrow your margin for error when making a vertical cut.

[image: Looks straight to me]
*This looks pretty straight*

[image: But it isn't]
*Close, but no cigar*

---

In this particular room, you *can't* cut from the same height as the beam, which makes saving all of the stones pretty impossible.  One thing you can try to do is cut from directly beneath the beam, but due to the nature of the physics, you'll pretty much always lose at least one of the stones no matter how straight you cut.

[image: Cutting from beneath]
*Cutting from beneath*

The good news is that this is the only situation in the entire game that I can think of where this happens.  Most of the other stones are tucked away in hard-to-see corners, or perched on hard-to-reach ledges, and the ones you *do* have to cut down are usually on top of pillars (and that's a whole other question).

---

There is an easier way to get all of the stones on this particular beam.  First, stand underneath it, and look to the far corner of the room.  There's another beam hanging under a ledge.  Cut it down, and use it to cross the gap.  It might take you a few tries, since the gap is wider at that end of the room.

[image: Cutting the second beam]

Now advance up the room normally until you're above the beam with the stones on it.  Then you can jump to it and collect all of the stones.

[image: Looking down on the stones]

Although, if you jump from here I think you'll die, so try jumping from a little ways down the ramp.  And when I say 'jump' I really mean 'step off'.  If you actually jump you'll probably die, depending on how high you are.  Experiment a little.

[image: Jumping from the ramp]

Once you've collected the stones you can either jump, or cut the beam down with you on top of it (jumping may kill you, forgot to test that) and be on your way.  Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the best way to do it in my opinion is cut it in half horizontally, then cut the bottom half down. That way, you get a bridge without touching the stones